# Pass CSV files through command line WITHOUT using file extension

Tags: c++

Say I have a program that passes CSV files through the command line, then uses a loop to parse relevant content into a struct.

The usage would be something like: Analyze 100 200 300 etc. Where Analyze is the name of the executable and 100 200 300 are CSV files.

I could get my program to work fine if the user enters the extension with the filename:

Analyze 100.csv 200.csv 300.csv etc, BUT I need my program to work without file extensions, example: Analyze 100 200 300 etc

Sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
                Testing T; //struct


                if (argc > 1) 
                {
                cout << "Loading . . . \n\n" << endl;
                } 
                else 
                {
                cout << "Usage: Analyze filename filename filename etc\n";
                return -1;
                }

                cout << "argc = " << argc << endl;

                for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                {

                ifstream infile(argv[i]); //open the file

                if (infile.is_open() && infile.good())
                    {

                        cout << "File is now open!\nContains:\n";
                        string line = "";

                while ( !infile.eof() )
                    {
                                    getline (infile, T.str);
                                    cout << "T.str: " << T.str << "\n";
                                    getline (infile, T.str2);
                                    cout << "T.str2: " << T.str2 << "\n";

                                    YADDA YADDA YADDA ...
```

Thanks

Comment: The extension of the file is completely irrelevant. If the file is named `100.csv` and the user enters "100", then manually concatenate `.csv` on the end. What's the problem?

Comment: You need to add the extension before opening the file.

Comment: @ChrisHayes so you're saying add ifstream infile(argv[i]".CSV")? I've been trying to do something like that and it's not working

Comment: That's because that isn't how you do string concatenation in C++. Google it.

Comment: @ChrisHayes yup. i didnt try googling for 2 hours before i asked my question.

Comment: Did you check to see whether `argv[i]".CSV"` was what you thought it was, before trying to feed it to `ifstream(...)`? Do you understand now that what you have is a string manipulation problem, not a file I/O problem? What do you still need help with?

Comment: @George You can google as long as you want, but if you're missing fundamental skills like knowing how to perform string concatenation, you're going to end up back on StackOverflow asking an awful lot of questions. I tried pointing you in the right direction. It should be clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
ifstream infile(argv[i] + std::string(".csv"));
```

If you don't have C++11 features, do:

```
std::string filename = argv[i] + std::string(".csv");
ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
```